# Player creation takes variable time in audiomath - can it be speeded up?

Tags: python, audio, portaudio, audiomath

I'm using [audiomath](https://pypi.org/project/audiomath) under Python 3.7 on Windows 10. I want to create `Player` instances ad-hoc at various times during a real-time application to play `Sound` instances that are already loaded into memory. It seems like these can sometimes be constructed very quickly (less than a millisecond) but sometimes it takes a couple of hundred milliseconds (which can disturb the timing of my application). I think this reflects the overhead of initializing PortAudio and/or opening streams but it's not clear to me when this does and does not happen. Is there a way of initializing everything ahead of time and/or optimizing things so that `Player` construction always happens fast?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that it takes time to initialize the library and the stream. It's also true that this overhead (at least, the stream-opening part) can happen at unexpected times if you're not keeping track of how many `Player` instances you have.  By default, a stream is created/opened/started implicitly and automatically when you create your first `Player`, and it gets stopped/closed/deleted automatically when no more `Player` instances are using it. Therefore, when your last `Player` instance gets garbage-collected, the stream will close: then if you subsequently create another one, you get the stream-initialization cost all over again. Perhaps that's explains your observation that it's "sometimes" slow and sometimes not?  The following results from IPython's `%timeit` tool illustrate how it works  (audiomath 1.5.1, Python 3.7.3, Windows 10):

```
import audiomath as am
s = am.TestSound('12')

timeit -n1 -r1     am.Player(s)
#  722 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
# First-ever Player: it took 722 ms to initialize the PortAudio
# library and opening a stream

timeit -n1 -r1     am.Player(s)
#  281 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
# The previous player was garbage-collected, so we're working off a
# blank slate, but the library is already initialized, so 281 is
# just the stream-opening overhead.

timeit -n1 -r1     am.Player(s)
#  283 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
# Same again.

p = am.Player(s) # now, let's keep a reference to an active Player 

timeit -n1 -r1     am.Player(s)
#  52.3 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
# With p still alive, creating another Player is really fast (although
# on some implementations such as macOS, even this can spend some tens
# of milliseconds just deciding which device should be used)
```

The cleanest way round this is to create a `Stream` instance explicitly, keep it alive throughout your session, and explicitly tell new `Player` instances to use it via their `stream=` constructor argument:

```
import audiomath as am
s = am.TestSound('12')
f = am.Stream()

timeit -n1 -r1    am.Player(s, stream=f)
# 50.3 µs ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
# All Players, even the first, are initialized lightning-fast
```

Just like `Player`, the `Stream` class is exported by the `audiomath.PortAudioInterface` back-end, and is available in the top-level namespace when that back-end is loaded (which it is by default).  It isn't well documented, but the input arguments worth knowing about (for specifying which API and device to use) are identical to those of [`audiomath.PortAudioInterface.FindDevices`](https://audiomath.readthedocs.io/en/release/source/audiomath.PortAudioInterface.html#audiomath.PortAudioInterface.FindDevices)